# AQTRONIX WebKnight 4.5

Tags: iis, web-application-firewall

I have downloaded AQTRONIX WebKnight 4.5 to test it out before purchasing the latest version.

I had a number of errors that I managed to fix, but I cannot work out how to fix the error where it's blocking some images

Below is a snippet of the log file showing the error, does anyone know what in the configuration I need to change to allow the images to show.

```
09:59:13 ; W3SVC8 ; OnUrlMap ; **.**.**.** ;  ; *****.com ; /app_data/cache/d/c/7/a/a/b/dc7aab408fbc0d0e6e0ebb1afb88c54ff5445725.webp ; BLOCKED: '/c/' not allowed in URL ; BLOCKED: '/d/' not allowed in URL ; *:\**\**\app_data\cache\d\c\7\a\a\b\dc7aab408fbc0d0e6e0ebb1afb88c54ff5445725.webp ; mode=max&width=2000&height=700&format=webp&quality=80&rnd=132685046925500000
```

Answer (score 0):

as the error line tells you:

> BLOCKED: '/c/' not allowed in URL ; BLOCKED: '/d/' not allowed in URL
> ;

you have to change the path of the image without using '/ c /' and '/ d /' for example use a real name or more than one character: '/ c1 /'

or go to the Webknight configurator section "URL Scanning" subsection "Denied URL sequences" and delete the values from the table.